# Type erasure prevents overloading, but allows overriding

Tags: java, generics, overriding, overloading, type-erasure

Could anyone explain to me why this is not allowed in Java? I have these three files (stripped and simplified for StackExchange):

A superclass, in my case for generic graphs. The type parameter indicates how arcs are represented: Either with a specific Arc class, or with Integers indicating unique IDs.

```
public interface Base<A> {
    public boolean removeArc(A arc);
}
```

A subclass, with a specific implementation for arc.

```
public interface Sub<B> extends Base<Arc<B>> {
    @Override
    public boolean removeArc(Arc<B> arc);

    public Arc<B> removeArc(B value); //Removes an arc with this specific value.
}
```

The arc implementation.

```
public interface Arc<B> {
}
```

Netbeans gives me the following compile-time errors in Sub. At @Override:

```
name clash: removeArc(Arc<B>) in Sub overrides a method whose erasure is the same as another method, yet neither overrides the other
  first method: removeArc(B) in Sub
  second method: removeArc(A) in Base
  where B,A are type-variables:
    B extends Object declared in interface Sub
    A extends Object declared in interface Base
```

At the second method:

```
name clash: removeArc(B) in Sub and removeArc(A) in Base have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
  where B,A are type-variables:
    B extends Object declared in interface Sub
    A extends Object declared in interface Base
```

The problem seems to be that `removeArc(Arc<B>)` and `removeArc(B)` have the same erasure, but I don't see why this is happening. Removing `removeArc(Arc<B>)` compiles fine, without warning about the `@Override`, so it must realise that `Arc<B>` equals `A` in `Base`.

Why is Java unable to differentiate between `Arc<B>` and `B` in this case?

Comment: This may be a bug in netbeans.  Eclipse does not complain about this code at all, so the issue isn't inherent to Java.  I'd generally try to avoid overloads like this though.

Comment: Aw, bugger if it is. I'll see if I can find if this is a known bug in Netbeans... Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be inherent in Java after all. I don't know why Eclipse doesn't complain, but javac gives me the same error.

Comment: The fix is easy.  Just use different names for the different methods.  There's no reason to name them the same.

Comment: Perhaps you're right, and I would rename the method as a last resort, but I'd still like to know the reason why this is disallowed. I tried to do it this way for clarity's sake, which is important in writing good interfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler removes generic classes at compile time. It will replace the place holder with it's restricted class.

In this case `Base` will replace any instance of `A` with `Object` and `Sub` will replace any instance of `B` with `Object`.

this gives the conflicting methods

in Base `public boolean removeArc(Object arc);`

and in Sub `public Arc removeArc(Object value);`

if however you did

```
public interface Base<A extends Arc<?>> {
    public boolean removeArc(A arc);
}
```

then the instances of `A` would be replaced with `Arc` and the method signatures would no longer conflict.

Comment: Doing it myself, I end up with `Base` having one method `removeArc(Object)`, and `Sub` having two methods `removeArc(Object)` and `removeArc(Arc)`, where `Sub#removeArc(Arc)` overrides `Base#removeArc(Object)`. Am I thinking about this wrong? I can't resort to your suggestion, as it defeats the purpose of having the generic argument: To be able to handle explicit `Arc`s as well as identifying arcs by their unique ID.

Comment: You are doing it correctly. Java is having an issue with the return types. Editted my response.

Comment: Still, including return types, I end up with `Base` having one method `boolean removeArc(Object)`, and `Sub` having two methods `Arc removeArc(Object)` and `boolean removeArc(Arc)`. I'd expect that `Base#removeArc(Object)` and `Sub#removeArc(Object)` wouldn't collide since `Base#removeArc(Object)` is no longer present, as it is overridden.

Comment: Nope does not work that way. Interface method signatures are merged not replaced.